# Как я могу обновить вложенный массив в Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript

Я использую Cloud Firestore в своем проекте. Как я могу обновить вложенный массив в объекте, `number[0]` например, без перезаписи всего объекта?

[image: объект]

Я использую метод:

```
async setNumberBookingDate(id) {
    const numberRef = doc(collection(this.db, "hotels"), id);

    await updateDoc(numberRef, {
      newP: 'xxxx'
    }
    );
}
```